# Breakpoints in SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

what is the use of breakpoints in SQL stored Procedures?? it doesnt serve same use as in visual studio.. it doesnt break execution?? then what is the use of adding it??
ELECT COUNT(P).ID)
    FROM #TempGetTable AS P
    WHERE P.Status  IN ('v','c')

```
AND COALESCE(P.ID,'') <> ''
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CERT TGR WHERE TGR.ProcessID = P.ID AND TGR.Type='Take')
AND P.ProcessName = 'Take'
```

I added a breakpoint in above code.. it runs same as even when there is no breakpoints.
Then why do we need to give that??

Comment: Have you setup SQL debugging?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billramo/archive/2009/04/12/transact-sql-debugger-for-sql-server-2008-part-3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running from management studio: to use breakpoints, you have to run it in debug mode instead of executing, that should stop on breakpoints.  (the green arrow or via the Debug menu)